# volvo xc70 cold starts into limp mode

Tags: volvo, cold-start, cold

2004 volvo xc70 awd inline 5 turbo, automatic-

Hello everyone, I've been having a fairly consistent problem that rears its ugly head almost every cold morning( ~ 8/10 times if its below 40F outside). What happens is as I start the car the limp mode message "reduced engine performance" appears. The car will not go above 2k and has an extremely rough idle. What i do is apply enough gas so it can idle smoothly around ~1700. I do this until the temp gauge has movement. I lock the car, come back 10 minutes later and viola all better! About 2/10 times after i come back the message remains but the vehicle runs fine.about ~1/25 times I need to let the vehicle sit again as it is still in limp mode.

I cant scan for codes as i am very far from the dealer and the codes will be gone after the 10 minute wait. After the vehicle is warmed up it never goes into limp mode even with multiple restarts and same thing if the weather is above 40. Hoping a Volvo guru who has seen this before can chime in on some potential ideas! Im thinking its something electrical but i cant imagine what wouldn't work below a certain temperature?

Comment: Have you had it checked for codes or are you assuming because the CEL and/or message goes away that there won't be any stored? Most vehicles will keep the codes stored at least for a while (might disappear after several starts). Really, I'd have it checked anyway if you've not done it. You can get a cheap ELM327 Bluetooth reader and the Torque app to read them on your own as well. I'd suspect the issue might lie with the engine coolant temperature (ETC) sensor, but wouldn't know for sure.